# Add functionality from wordpress dashboard to define images on hover

Tags: php, wordpress, html, wordpress-theming

I am working on a site similar to http://box.techaspirants.com/loan/ 
the page has 3 images:
1) if you hover on the left, it will show image1.
2) if you hover on the right, it will show image2.
3) if the mouse is idle, image3 will be displayed.

I created html for the same style and it is working perfectly fine in HTML5. Then the same is considered as slide1. Similar is applied to 2 other slides and hover effect is applied for all the images.

I want to convert it into WordPress, with the ability for users to add image1, image2, image3 and then embed the same into a slider.

I tried with different post types and I even searched for plugin but didn't find any.

Any help, advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems the link text in the above message has error, check this http://box.techaspirants.com/loan

Answer (score 0):

Create post type and then 
You can add your image 1 in featured image and 
create 2 meta box for upload image
and then add your 2 and 3 image in it.

This meta box will add images in all posts and then fetch it on front end